# Grid gain : Thin client - key value cache - CRUD operations using non-primary key column

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I would like to know, is there a way to do CRUD operations using non primary key for a cache defined in grid gain using thin client API (Not by using sql query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using SQL, Ignite is basically a key-value store. You could use a ScanQuery, which iterates over every record in the named cache.

But really, the answer is to use SQL.